# Who am I... Password Denied?

Tags: cipher

As an agent for the CIA, you are forced to take the test to re-validate your membership. Surprisingly, they send you a cryptogram no test-taker has been able to solve. The answer is quite clear to the guys who made the cryptogram, but hard to those who didn't:

> 745692789632147412369 741253698521478963! 
> 9874156147896398745632198745632174125369789632147418953741268  7412689874123514789638529874123574126!

The only hint they would ever give that it is two phrases ending in `!` and each string of numbers represents a word. So what is the message anyways?

> 745692789632147412369 = ? 
>     741253698521478963! = ? 
>     9874156147896398745632198745632174125369789632147418953741268 = ? 
>     7412689874123514789638529874123574126! = ?

Comment: You sure there's not some digits missing? I get the first phrase, and can make a partial fit/guess at the second based on the title, but it seems like it gets "corrupted" in the second phrase (especially word three).

Comment: Like @Alconja, I think I get the answer, but the last letter of the third word seems to be missing, and the first two letters of that word aren't great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure the message is:

> YOU WIN! PASSWORD DENIED!

Found by using the numbers given to:

> trace out individual letter patterns on the number pad of a keyboard.

So specifically, letter by letter:

> 745692 = **Y**
>  78963214 = **O** (though arguably needs an extra 7 at the end)
>  7412369 = **U**
>  ---
>  74125369 = **W**
>  852 = **I**
>  1478963 = **N** (looks like a lower case N)
>  ---
>  9874156 = **P** (though probably should have an extra 9)
>  1478963 = **A** (though it actually looks the same as the "N" above)
>  987456321 = **S**
>  987456321 = **S**
>  74125369 = **W**
>  78963214 = **O** (needs another 7)
>  7418953 = **R**
>  741268 = **D**
>  ---
>  741268 = **D**
>  98741235 = **E** (though you have to squint a bit)
>  1478963 = **N** (as above)
>  852 = **I**
>  98741235 = **E**
>  74126 = **D** (edit that fixed the end of "password" seems to have dropped the last "8" though to close the D)

...though I've got to admit, I don't really understand the purpose of the "Who am I?" in the title, or the actual meaning of the message, so it's possible there's more to it.

Comment: The title was to mislead the users. I guess it was a little too misleading but great job!